# Prove that the subspace of the real numbers spanned by the powers of an algebraic number form a finite-dimensional subspace over the rationals

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I am reading through some [old Linear Algebra lectures](http://math.stanford.edu/~akshay/math113.html) and came across the following claim:

[image: nea]

I am unsure how to show that $V$ is finite-dimensional. I understand that since $\alpha$ is algebraic there exists a polynomial $p$ with integer coefficients such that $p(\alpha) = 0$, which in turn implies the list of powers $(1, \alpha, \alpha^{2}, \dots)$ is not linearly independent. I am assuming I am meant to use this fact to argue that only the powers up to the degree of $p(\alpha)$ are needed to form a basis/spanning set, but I cannot see how to do this. Any help would be appreciated. I am using the following definition of algebraic:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and suppose it has degree $n$. We can show that $\{1, \alpha, \alpha^2,...,\alpha^{n-1}\}$ is indeed a basis of your space. First we show that this set is linearly independent. Indeed, suppose $c_0+c_1\alpha+c_2\alpha^2+...c_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1}=0$ where the coefficients are in $\mathbb{Q}$. Then $p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} c_kx^k$ is a polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ which satisfies $p(\alpha)=0$. Since it has lower degree than $m$ it must be the zero polynomial, hence $c_0=c_1=...=c_{n-1}=0$.

Now we prove the set is spanning the space. A general element in this space has the form $c_0+c_1\alpha+c_2\alpha^2+...c_t\alpha^t$ where $t\in\mathbb{N}$ and the coefficients are rational. So let $p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^t c_kx^k\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$. We can divide this polynomial by $m$ with remainder. There are polynomials $q,r\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $p=qm+r$ and $0\leq \deg(r)<\deg(m)=n$. So now we have:

$r(\alpha)=p(\alpha)-q(\alpha)m(\alpha)=p(\alpha)$

Hence now writing $r(x)=d_0+d_1x+...+d_{n-1}x^{n-1}$ (the degree might be lower than $n-1$ but we just add zeros if needed) we get $p(\alpha)=d_0+d_1\alpha+...+d_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $p(\alpha) = 0$ where $p$ has degree $d$ and rational coefficients, you can express each $\alpha^j$ for nonnegative integer $j$ as a linear combination with rational coefficients of $1, \alpha, \ldots, \alpha^{d-1}$.  Prove by induction on $j$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $F$ be a field and let $F[x]$ be the ring of polynomials with co-efficients in $F.$ If $f(x),g(x)\in F[x]$ and deg $f(x)>0$ then there exists $h(x), j(x)\in F[x]$ with deg $j(x)<$ deg $f(x)$ and $g(x)=f(x)h(x)+j(x).$

Let $F=\Bbb Q$ and let $f(x)\in \Bbb Q[x]$ with deg $f(x)=n>0.$ And suppose $\alpha\in \Bbb R$ such that $f(\alpha)=0.$

If $y$ belongs to the $V$ of the Q then $y=g(\alpha)$ for some $g(x)\in \Bbb Q[x].$ So let $g(x)=f(x)h(x)+j(x)$ where $h(x),j(x)\in \Bbb Q[x]$ with deg $j(x)<$ deg $f(x)=n.$

So $y=g(\alpha)=f(\alpha)h(\alpha)+j(\alpha)=j(\alpha).$

So $y=j(\alpha)$ belongs to the vector space over $\Bbb Q$ spanned by $\{\alpha^m: 0\le m\le n-1\},$ which is finite-dimensional (of dimension $n$ or less) over $\Bbb Q.$

(In case $\alpha=0,$ in the preceding paragraph, when $m=0$ we follow the common convention that $0^0=1.$)